# How to restore openoffice file?

Tags: openoffice.org, data-recovery

I have worked in a file for 4 months. All of a sudden when i open that file this morning its not getting opened. And i have noticed the size got decreased to 128KB to 1KB. Not only my system, recently we are facing this problem in many systems. Data is getting corrupted and we cant able to open the file. What may be the issue ? And is it possible to recover the data? I hardly need those datas, can anyone help me pls. Thanks in advance..

**Details:**

- Ubuntu 10.10
- Open office 3.2.1

Comment: If data is important to you, you should never have to ask anyone if it's recoverable. You should always know that you have a backup and how to restore from it. I hope you'll find a good answer, but in any case: backup!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your open office backup folder

```
/home/<user name>/.openoffice.org/3/user
```

Sources:
http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=16040
http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=12426